# Error deploying sample widget in Lotus Connections

Tags: xml, widget, lotus, ibm-connections

I'm learning to work with widget in lotus connections and got a tutorial that teaches how to make a simple widget, but when I published, within the widget appeared this error:

BMWIW0001E: Unable to load iWidget 'https://myserver/homepage/web/getWidgetDescriptor.action?widgetId=91a5468a-06b1-4760-b8b5-c7def77d4d88'.arg1 is null.

Here is the xml code:

```
<iw:iwidget name="helloWorld" xmlns:iw="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/iWidget">
<iw:content mode="view">
<![CDATA[
     <div>
          <div id="helloWorld">Hello World!</div>
     </div>
]]>
</iw:content>
</iw:iwidget>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to that tutorial or at least a little bit more background on the systems used, ...?

Comment: Here is the link:  http://wpcertification.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/deploying-custom-widget-on-connections.html

Comment: As you are accessing the iWidget via https - what certificate are you using for that? Does the Webserver use a certificate, that Connections can read without importing some root certificates into Connections first?

Comment: I'm using the certificate created during Lotus Connections installation and the webserver use this certicate and Connections Server can read normaly without import any root certificates. I'm wondering if there's a default folder to alocate the widget application?

Answer (score 0):

The error "arg1 is null" shows that the widget container couldn't retrieve the widget definition successfully. Can you show us the list of properties you used to register your widget with Homepage?